# Android cast notification not working in lock screen

Tags: android, casting, notifications, google-cast

I implemented the cast sender notification exactly like this: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#add_media_controls_to_notification_and_lock_screen

And its working like a charm when the phone is unlocked, unfortunately nothing happens when I click on the pause button in the lock screen.
Does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong? I'm on API 29.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, tried everything, AlarmManger, WakeLock, IgnoreBatteryOptimization, disabled the manufacturer battery optimization app. Everything works like a charm in the emulator, but on my S7 Edge (Android 8.0) does not work. OEM are destroying the apps which needs to work in background, if you find a solution let me know please

Comment: Unfortunately it's a known bug on Samsung devices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this seems to be a known bug on Samsung devices: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127272573